# How to read PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing a quick PHP project that takes information from another file and reads it and gathers the information. The websites stores information like this:

Filename: `.ipn`

```
 Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 10.00
    [ipn_track_id] => 731ea17d
)
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 10.00
    [ipn_track_id] => 523fd7886
)
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 10.00
    [ipn_track_id] => 523fd7886
)
```

How would I create a PHP script that takes the .ipn file and sums up the overall `[mc_gross]`, which in this case would be `30.00`?

Comment: is that the exact contents of the .ipn file?

Comment: You should save the array as JSON. `json_encode($array);` and `json_decode($file);`.

Comment: What generates the `.ipn`? That's a very unconventional format and not very mark-up friendly. You *could* parse it, but you'd be better off working with XML, JSON, or YML

Comment: You can use a regular expression for this - just match on the literal `[mc_gross] => ` followed by any number of `[0-9.]`. Give that a go, and let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
<?php
        $input = file_get_contents("filename.ext");
        $regexp = "/\[mc_gross\][ ]*=>[ ]*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/";
        $sum = 0;
        if(preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
            foreach($matches as $match) {
                $sum += $match[1];
            }
            unset($match);
        }
        echo "Sum ".$sum;

/*
    var_dumping the matches - 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '[mc_gross] => 10.00' (length=19)
          1 => string '10.00' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string '[mc_gross] => 10.00' (length=19)
          1 => string '10.00' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array
          0 => string '[mc_gross] => 10.00' (length=19)
          1 => string '10.00' (length=5)
*/

?>
```

Comment: What would I type inside the regexp if I wanted to print out an array of string that would be named [mc_name] everytime.

Comment: mc_name instead of mc_gross?? just replace mc_gross to mc_name Like this **"/\[mc_name\][ ]*=>[ ]*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/"** .

Comment: Additionally, if you have [mc_gross] and [mc_name] occuring in different arrays and want to find sum of both the entries, you can use this **"/\[(?:(?:mc_gross)|(?:mc_name))\][ ]*=>[ ]*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/"**

Comment: The problem is that your code seems to only take numbers, not strings.

Comment: Oh ok you did not specify that. I took the format to be concrete.
Use this for names - **/\[mc_name\][ ]*=>[ ]*([a-zA-Z]+)/**

Comment: That still doesn't seem to allow characters such as @, - and _.

Comment: Try this - /[mc_name][ ]*=>[ ]*(.*?)/

Answer (score 0):

First, save the array to the files using [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize).

```
$string = serialize($array);
file_put_contents('myfile.ipn',serialize($string));
```

Then, read the file using [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$content = file_get_contents('myfile.ipn');
$array = unserialize($content);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if OP has no influence on how the file that he wants to read is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

```
$lines = array_chunk(file('items.ipn'),5);
$sum = 0;
foreach($lines as $line){
  $sum += floatval(end(explode('=>',$line[2])));
}
print $sum;
// 30
```